# How to add a maximum travel time duration for the sum of all routes in VRP Google OR-TOOLS

Tags: time, or-tools, vehicle-routing, pressure

I am new to programming and used Google OR-tools to create my VRP model. In my current model, I have included a general time window and capacity constraint per vehicle, creating a capacitated vehicle routing problem with time windows. I followed the OR-tools guides which contains a maximum travel duration for each vehicle.

However, I want to include a maximum travel duration for the sum of all routes, whereas the maximum travel duration for each vehicle does not matter (so I set it to 100.000). Accorddingly, I want to create something in the model/solution printer that tells me which amount of addresses could not be visited due to the constraint on the maximum travel duration for the sum of all routes. From the examples I have seen I think it would be kind of easy, but my knowledge on programming is fairly limited, so my attempts had no succes. Can anyone help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import math
from random import sample
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist
from haversine import haversine


#STEP - create data
# import/read excel file
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Jean-Paul\Documents\Thesis\OR TOOLS\Data.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['number','lat','lng'])                        # create dataframe with 10805 addresses + address of the depot
#print (df)

# randomly sample X addresses from the dataframe and their corresponding number/latitude/longtitude
df_sample = df.sample(n=100)
#print (df_data)

# read first row of the excel file (= coordinates of the depot)
df_depot = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['number','lat','lng']).iloc[0:1]
#print (df_depot)

# combine dataframe of depot and sample into one dataframe
df_data = pd.concat([df_depot, df_sample], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
#print (df_data)


#STEP - create distance matrix data
# determine distance between latitude and longtitude
df_data.set_index('number', inplace=True)
matrix_distance = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df_data, metric=haversine)), index=df_data.index, columns=df_data.index)
matrix_list = np.array(matrix_distance)
#print (matrix_distance)                                                        # create table of distances between addresses including headers
#print (matrix_list)                                                            # converting table to list of lists and exclude headers

#STEP - create time matrix data
travel_time = matrix_list / 15 * 60                                             # divide distance by travel speed 20 km/h and multiply by 60 minutes
#print (travel_time)                                                            # converting distance matrix to travel time matrix


#STEP - create time window data
# create list for each sample - couriers have to visit this address within 0-X minutes of time using a list of lists
window_range = []
for i in range(len(df_data)):
    list = [0, 240]
    window_range.append(list)                                                   # create list of list with a time window range for each address
#print (window_range)


#STEP - create demand data
# create list for each sample - all addresses demand 1 parcel except the depot
demand_range = []
for i in range(len(df_data.iloc[0:1])):
    list = 0
    demand_range.append(list)
for j in range(len(df_data.iloc[1:])):
    list2 = 1
    demand_range.append(list2)
#print (demand_range)


#STEP - create fleet size data              # amount of vehicles in the fleet
fleet_size = 6
#print (fleet_size)


#STEP - create capacity data for each vehicle
fleet_capacity = []
for i in range(fleet_size):                 # capacity per vehicle
    list = 20
    fleet_capacity.append(list)
#print (fleet_capacity)


#STEP - create data model that stores all data for the problem
def create_data_model():
    data = {}
    data['time_matrix'] = travel_time
    data['time_windows'] = window_range
    data['num_vehicles'] = fleet_size
    data['depot'] = 0                     # index of the depot
    data['demands'] = demand_range
    data['vehicle_capacities'] = fleet_capacity
    return data


#STEP - creating the solution printer
def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    total_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2}) -> '.format(
                manager.IndexToNode(index), solution.Min(time_var),
                solution.Max(time_var))
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    solution.Min(time_var),
                                                    solution.Max(time_var))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}min\n'.format(
            solution.Min(time_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += solution.Min(time_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))


#STEP - create the VRP solver
def main():
    # instantiate the data problem
    data = create_data_model()

    # create the routing index manager
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    # create routing model
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


#STEP - create demand callback and dimension for capacity
    # create and register a transit callback
    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,                              # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],     # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,                           # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')


#STEP - create time callback
    # create and register a transit callback
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

    # define cost of each Arc (costs in terms of travel time)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)


# STEP - create a dimension for the travel time (TIMEWINDOW) - dimension keeps track of quantities that accumulate over a vehicles route
# add time windows constraint
    time = 'Time'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        2,                           # allow waiting time (does not have an influence in this model)
        100000,                      # maximum total route lenght in minutes per vehicle (does not have an influence because of capacity constraint)
        False,                       # do not force start cumul to zero
        time)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)

# add time window constraints for each location except depot
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
        if location_idx == data['depot']:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])

# add time window constraint for each vehicle start node
    depot_idx = data['depot']
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][0],
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][1])


#STEP - instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times
    for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))


#STEP - setting default search parameters and a heuristic method for finding the first solution
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)


#STEP - solve the problem with the serach parameters and print solution
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

See @Mizux's answer, going under-the-hood in the solver to make a summation cost over all vehicle route lengths:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68756570/13773745

Comment: Please see [answering questions with links to other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/answering-questions-with-links-to-other-answers-on-stackoverflow)